# How to clean STDIN in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, stdin

How to clean STDIN in Ruby? I want to be sure that nothing is left in STDIN.

Comment: What do you mean by clean?

Comment: I mean removing all the buffered characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if there is input available in STDIN using `IO#ready?` from `io/wait`.
Use `IO#getc` to read a character, removing it from the buffer.

```
require 'io/wait'

def clear_stdin
  $stdin.getc while $stdin.ready?
end
```